# Can a ResultSet be used to directly populate a table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I've got a lot of database tables that I need to modify the data in that I'm going to be doing with Java. For reasons beyond my control, I'll be querying each table, getting a set of data from it, and loading that data into a separate table. What is the fastest most efficient way to do this? Can I just take the ResultSet from the Statement object and somehow use that to populate the new table? Or do I need to iterate through the ResultSet and re-insert the rows into the new table row by row with a PreparedStatement or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating new tables, you can do

```
 CREATE TABLE whatever AS
 SELECT something FROM sometable WHERE somecondition
```

This is a powerful capability. Read about it here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html

If your target tables already exist you can use

```
INSERT INTO whatever  (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM sometable WHERE somecondition
```

This too is powerful.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html

In both cases this is an efficient way to do things; your data doesn't have to travel from MySQL server to client and back.

It's easy to issue this kind of SQL command from JDBC. Use the `execute()` method of a `Statement` object.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you, and thank you for pointing out it can be done through JDBC since I have to do this using java.

Answer (score 1):

the fastest most efficient way to do this would be to do [the whole thing in SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp), like

```
INSERT INTO table2
 SELECT * FROM table1;
```